# jQuery applying a function on each row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects. I have to apply a function to each row and Log the corresponding name and id.

Here is my code:

```
var json = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Jon",
        age:  20

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Jessy",
        age:  25

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Sarah",
        age:  30

    },
]

console.log(json)
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-info'>Log</button>" + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);

}
```

Using jQuery how can I apply the function and Log the id and name? 
on click of a button i need to log the id and name. Each button will log their cell's name and id

so if the button in first row clicked , it should log `id: 1 , name: jon`

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Apply what function? Why not just `console.log(json[i].id, json[i].name)` inside the loop?

Comment: sorry for not writing properly, on click of a button i need to log the id and name. Each button will log their cell's name and id

Comment: You can just use a forEach to iterate through the array (with Object.keys() in a closure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```js
var json = [{id:1,name:"Jon",age:20}, {id:2,name:"Jessy",age:25}, {id:3,name:"Sarah",age:30}];

//console.log(json)
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='btn btn-info'>Log</button>" + "</td>");
  $('table').append(tr);
}

// Attach a delegated event handler
$('table').on('click', '.btn-info', function(event) {
  console.log('ID: ' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());
  console.log('Name: ' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` method to loop your array and then create each row with `td` and `button` and add click event to button.

```js
const json = [{"id":1,"name":"Jon","age":20},{"id":2,"name":"Jessy","age":25},{"id":3,"name":"Sarah","age":30}]
const tbody = $("table tbody");

json.forEach(function(obj) {
  let { id, name} = obj;
  
  let btn = $('<button>', {"class": 'btn btn-info'})
    .text('Log')
    .click(function() {
      console.log('ID: ' + id, 'Name: ' + name)
    })

  let tr = $("<tr>")
    .append($('<td>').text(id))
    .append($('<td>').text(name))
    .append($('<td>').html(btn))

  tbody.append(tr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```